# How to install my HP Pavilion dv6559ea fingerprint reader on Ubuntu?

Tags: hp-pavilion, fingerprint-reader

It's my first time with Linux OS and I'm trying to install properly my fingerprint reader, but I'm not even close to it.
Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar HP DV model and, at least the last time I checked, there wasn't actually a driver for it.  There, was however, a rather geeky app that permits you to play with it.  I refer to fprint-demo, available in the Ubuntu Software Center.  The about page is linked here:  http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/  Alternately you can install it by opening this link and clicking on the orange button:  https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/fprint-demo/

Comment: Hello , gyropyge.
I downloaded it but it doesn't work. When it asks me to enroll my fingerprints, I try to do it but it seems it doesn't sense it. It's like I'm not enrolling my fingers at all. Any sugestions?
Thanks.

Comment: The "demo" software I tried was strange and buggy when I tried it, but nonetheless rather fun.  It is entirely possible that between that software and your hardware, an actual driver is also called for.  I recommend opening your system settings and once there, click on "additional drivers".  It might detect your fingerprint reader and install a driver for it.